# render html data stored in variable in function of .module file in page.tpl.php file

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have just started using drupal and am little bit confused with the flow. I have a variable `$var = "<div>Render in View</div>"` in a function in my .module file. How do I render this exact html in the page.tpl.php file?

Thanks

Comment: you are missing a semi -colon at end of your line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7

```
function mymodule_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'page') {
    $variables['my_custom_page_var'] = '<div>Render in page.tpl.php</div>';
  }
}
```

or use the dynamic hook name

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_custom_page_var'] = '<div>Render in page.tpl.php</div>';
}
```

Then this should be accessible in page.tpl.php as `$my_custom_page_var`.